# lightweight python gui window

Tags: python, matplotlib, user-interface

I have written a numerical solver in python that iteratively solves for a solution. However, like every other numerical solver, it can diverge if the step size or boundary conditions are not defined properly. I would like to have a lightweight GUI window that shows the residues after every iteration so that I can see how my boundary conditions and steps size affect the algorithm. However, the only way I know to do so is to use a `mapltolib` window with `plt.show(block=False)`. However, using `matplotlib` slows down the program drastically, and I was wondering if there is an alternative lightweight GUI interface I can use.

Thanks.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you want from your question. Can you show some code?

Comment: I personally have done similar things and have not experienced "drastical slow down" from including matplotlib plots. Hard to tell what's happening in your case without code samples. Anyhow, have you considered separating the "solving" from the "plotting", i.e. writing your residuals to file and using that as input for a separate "gui analysis" script for plotting?